# Pesquisa SQL - Resultados não duplicados

Tags: sql, algoritmo-de-busca

Estou querendo retornar uma pesquisa do banco de dados sem dados repetidos. A table se chama `Wps_history` e contem as seguintes colunas:

```
id
user_id
adm_user_id
type
user
lancamento
data
valor
saldo
reason
ip
inserted
```

Estou fazendo a pesquisa da seguinte maneira:

```
select * 
from wps_history 
where inserted between "2016-11-01 00:00:00" AND "2016-11-30 23:59:59";
```

Só que estou recebendo dados duplicados de usuário, o que preciso fazer é filtrar o resultado pelo `user_id`.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa usar a cláusula `DISTINCT`com a coluna que você quer o dado único:

```
select DISTINCT(user_id) from wps_history where inserted between "2016-11-01 00:00:00" AND "2016-11-30 23:59:59"
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente. Aproveitar sua ajuda, consigo verificar a frequência que estes usuários usam meu sistema?

Exemplo:

Usuário: user_id: 4435

Consigo ver usando a coluna: data, para ver quantas vezes no mês este usuário entra no site?

Valeu!

Comment: @CíceroAlves o ideal nas novas dúvidas que surgirem é que você crie outra pergunta para que outras pessoas possam te auxiliar focados na sua dúvida

Comment: Obrigado, farei isso. Não criei um novo por que não li as regras, fiquei com medo de ser proibido!

Valeu!